# Multiple upload of .json in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, file-upload

I have unblocked .json files in SharePoint. I am able to upload one by one. But when I try to upload multiple .json files then I have a problem and doesn't let me. Does anyone know a solution in order to be able to upload multiple .json files?

p.s. I can provide more details if needed

Answer (score 0):

The SharePoint web application has Enable additional actions and Online Status for members disabled. Check this Microsoft [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2691367) for the solution.

Comment: Nope it is not the case. It is enabled. I checked many articles about how to enable Multiple upload. the issue is that cannot upload multiple .json files